Iterating over a list and conditionals in tabular environment not working. Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 72
i work on a project with a lot of people and there are many who are not really familiar with LaTeX. Therefore, I have to define a command (\timeplan{}), which simplifies coloring tablecells (each column represent an annual quarter for the years 2025 2026 2027 and 2028.
example: \timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1} should color the cell of column 25Q3 and 27Q1.
I was expecting my command to work, because it does in the normal paragraph environment (see below).
But somehow my written code doesn't work in a tabular environment.
I get many errors:

Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line...
Missing } inserted.
Extra \else.
Extra \fi.
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
Extra \fi.
Extra \else.
Extra \fi.
Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line...

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{ctable} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\RequirePackage{zref-savepos}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}

\definecolor{tablecolor}{RGB}{219,229,241}
\newcommand{\coloredcell}{\cellcolor{tablecolor}}
\newcounter{quartalcount}
\setcounter{quartalcount}{0}
\newcommand{\helperfct}[2]{%
    \forcsvlist{\listadd\subset}{#1}
    \ifinlist{#2}{\subset}{%
    \ifnum\value{quartalcount}<16
        \coloredcell \stepcounter{quartalcount} & 
    \else
         \coloredcell \stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \fi
    }{%
    \ifnum\value{quartalcount}<16
        \ifnum\value{quartalcount}=0 %Workaround with dummy as first entry
            \stepcounter{quartalcount}
        \else
             \stepcounter{quartalcount} & 
        \fi
    \else
        \stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \fi}
}
\newcommand{\timeplan}[1]{\setcounter{quartalcount}{0}
\forcsvlist{\listgadd\fulllist}{Dummy, 25Q1, 25Q2,25Q3, 25Q4,26Q1,26Q2,26Q3,26Q4,27Q1,27Q2,27Q3,27Q4,28Q1,28Q2,28Q3,28Q4} %Somehow the first entry will always be false (don't know why) therefore I did a  workaround with a dummy.
\forlistloop{\helperfct{#1}}{\fulllist}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{p{0.0625\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
     \hline
     \timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

If I use \textbackslash and & outside of my tabular environment it looks, how i want it to be.

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{ctable} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\RequirePackage{zref-savepos}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}

\definecolor{tablecolor}{RGB}{219,229,241}
\newcommand{\coloredcell}{\cellcolor{tablecolor}}
\newcounter{quartalcount}
\setcounter{quartalcount}{0}
\newcommand{\helperfct}[2]{%
    \forcsvlist{\listadd\subset}{#1}
    \ifinlist{#2}{\subset}{%
    \ifnum\value{quartalcount}<16
        \textbackslash coloredcell \stepcounter{quartalcount} \& 
    \else
         \textbackslash coloredcell \stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \fi
    }{%
    \ifnum\value{quartalcount}<16
        \ifnum\value{quartalcount}=0 %Workaround with dummy as first entry
            \stepcounter{quartalcount}
        \else
             \stepcounter{quartalcount} \& 
        \fi
    \else
        \stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \fi}
}
\newcommand{\timeplan}[1]{\setcounter{quartalcount}{0}
\forcsvlist{\listgadd\fulllist}{Dummy, 25Q1, 25Q2,25Q3, 25Q4,26Q1,26Q2,26Q3,26Q4,27Q1,27Q2,27Q3,27Q4,28Q1,28Q2,28Q3,28Q4} %Somehow the first entry will always be false (don't know why) therefore I did a  workaround with a dummy.
\forlistloop{\helperfct{#1}}{\fulllist}
}
\begin{document}
What I want to generate by my Command \verb|\timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}|\\ (here i used \verb|\textbackslash coloredcell| and \verb|\&| instead of \verb|\coloredcell| and \verb|&|): \par
\vspace{1ex}
\timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}\par
\vspace{2ex}
How the Output should look like (Here i used \verb|&&\coloredcell&&&&&&\coloredcell&&&&&&&| instead of \verb|\timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}|:\\
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{p{0.0625\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
     \hline
     &&\coloredcell&&&&&&\coloredcell&&&&&&&\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Can someone help please? :)
Cheers

You need to collect the tabular information in a token list, and then output the token list all at once, when the process is complete.  To see what I mean, look in my code for instances of \addtotoks, which is where I add information into the token list.  And for \mytoks, which is the name of the token list itself.
EDITED to reset \fulllist, which was otherwise accumulating.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{ctable} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\RequirePackage{zref-savepos}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtotoks[1]{\global\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks#1}}
\definecolor{tablecolor}{RGB}{219,229,241}
\newcommand{\coloredcell}{\cellcolor{tablecolor}}
\newcounter{quartalcount}
\setcounter{quartalcount}{0}
\newcommand{\helperfct}[2]{%
    \forcsvlist{\listadd\subset}{#1}
    \ifinlist{#2}{\subset}{%
    \ifnum\value{quartalcount}<16
        \addtotoks{\coloredcell  &}\stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \else
        \addtotoks{\coloredcell }\stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \fi
    }{%
    \ifnum\value{quartalcount}<16
        \ifnum\value{quartalcount}=0 %Workaround with dummy as first entry
            \stepcounter{quartalcount}
        \else
             \stepcounter{quartalcount} \addtotoks{ &}
        \fi
    \else
        \stepcounter{quartalcount}
    \fi}
}
\newcommand{\timeplan}[1]{\mytoks{}\let\fulllist\empty
\setcounter{quartalcount}{0}
\forcsvlist{\listgadd\fulllist}{Dummy, 25Q1, 25Q2,25Q3, 25Q4,26Q1,26Q2,26Q3,26Q4,27Q1,27Q2,27Q3,27Q4,28Q1,28Q2,28Q3,28Q4} %Somehow the first entry will always be false (don't know why) therefore I did a  workaround with a dummy.
\forlistloop{\helperfct{#1}}{\fulllist}
\the\mytoks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{p{0.0625\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
     \hline
     \timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{p{0.0625\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
     \hline
     \timeplan{25Q4, 26Q2}\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



Thank you for your respond. But when insert the command two times or more, \timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}\\timeplan{25Q3, 27Q1}\, in my table, the last cell is always colored

@Viggo \fulllist needed to be reset each time, otherwise it was just accumulating in length.
